# Print preview function using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, print-preview

I use jquery scripts for modal popup functionality in user controls and in master page.The problem is when i use a print preview function in jquery to capture the entire page, the basic scripts like jquery 1.7.1.min.js gets conflict and the print preview function does not works.If i remove the script reference in my user control, my functionality will not work but the print preview function works.

I tried like dis. I removed the script reference in usercontrol and added like dis in the masterpage.

```
var control = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
control.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
control.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ResolveClientUrl("../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"));
this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(control);
```

I used jQuery Print Previw Plugin v1.0.1 for the print preview function and edited for the preview. But i still get the error as

```
$("a.print-preview").printPreview is not a function
[Break On This Error] $('a.print-preview').printPreview();
```

and print preview function doesnt work.. Any suggestions ??

EDIT :
I found a little . I used $.noConflict(); and found the print preview function is working  but some other script functionalities are not working in the page.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your page doesn't see the plugin. Make sure that the print plugin added correctly.

Comment: only when the script reference is present in either masterpage or user control page , the print preview jquery works..but when i add like dis on the masterpage, the preview plugin is not called . how to call d script.?

Comment: If you add this, $("a.print-preview").printPreview to a page, you should add its plugin too. Jquery itself doesn't have the command 'printPreview'. So, you should add the plugin that contains, 'printPreview' command to the page you used $("a.print-preview").printPreview.

Comment: yes i have added the plugin. it is working fine. my problem is when I add <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in master page and usercontrol at the time only this print preview plugin not working.

Comment: I hope you know that, you cannot use two jquery library at the same page. So i will tell something more specific;

Jquery library is a library that still growing and getting bigger. But they should get rid of the old commands out of it. Maybe your plugin using the a retired jquery command that belongs the old versions. Maybe you should give a try to the some older jquery versions.

Comment: I removed the older versions and i tried with the latest versions, The prob is printpreview function is not called when these basic scripts are added.